# Illegal Instruction ARM Assembly Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: assembly, arm, raspberry-pi4

I am trying assembly code for the first time on my Raspberry Pi 4 (sorry if the code isn't formatted in a standard way) and I am trying to execute my Hello World code

```
.global _start

_start:
mov r0, #1
ldr r1, =helloworld
mov r2, #12
mov r8, #64
svc 0
mov r0, #0
mov r8, #93
svc 0

.data
helloworld: .ascii "Hello World\n"
```

The code compiles with no errors but when I try to execute my code with ./HelloWorld I get the arror "Illegal Instruction" with no other messages. Any ideas on what is going on?

Comment: Use a debugger and/or strace. I assume your last svc call is wrong so it does not terminate the process and the cpu continues executing.

Comment: Also consult documentation. Using `r8` is suspicious, also the numbers are strange. What OS are you using?

Comment: I found my issue, the book I'm learning from says I need to run a 64-bit version of Linux on my raspberry pi but right now I'm running 32-bit raspbian.

Comment: @LordBobbiousX Assembly for ARM64 and ARM32 differs considerably.  I am surprised you didn't notice.  You cannot run ARM64 programs on 32 bit Raspbian.

Answer (score 1):

You are using 64-bit system call numbers and ABI in a 32-bit assembly language, which is presumably in a 32-bit process which doesn't work.

Either put the 32-bit system call number in r7 (write = 4, exit = 1) or use 64-bit assembly language (different register names) in a 64-bit process.

Comment: Note that the Linux system call numbers differ on all architectures.  There are no “64 bit system call numbers” or “32 bit system call numbers.”  Instead, there are “i386 system call numbers,” “amd64 system call numbers,” “ARM EABI system call numbers,” and so on.